# CSS3 border-radius using solitary number (unitless value) is not working

Tags: html, css

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) states that you can use a number from 1-4 as the length property but it has no effect.

Any reason for this?

```css
p {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 4;
}
```

```html
<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, 'and what is the use of a book,'
  thought Alice 'without pictures or conversations?'</p>
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/6L31f9d6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** The points indicated by Thieu Nguyen are valid. I am adding a separate answer because I think ***your problem is due to the interpretation (wrong) of the formal syntax*** and because I'm not comfortable forcing my content into another answer.

The [MDN page for `border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) nowhere states that we can use a number from 1-4 as the length value. In fact, all length values in CSS ***must be*** followed by a unit and the only exception to this is 0.

The below is the extract from the [CSS Spec for Length Units](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#length-units): (emphasis is mine)

> The format of a length value is an optional sign character ('+' or '-', with '+' being the default) immediately followed by a number (with or without a decimal point) ***immediately followed by a unit identifier*** (a two-letter abbreviation). After a '0' number, the unit identifier is optional.

---

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35930208/css3-border-radius-using-solitary-number-not-working#comment59519380_35930324), I get the feeling that you are confusing the `{1,4}` in the formal syntax to be unitless values.

> [ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} [ / [ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} ]?

But they are not unitless values. It is ***like in RegEx*** where `[a]{x,y}` means *minimum x occurrences* and *maximum y occurrences of a*. So, the below is how the formal syntax should be interpreted:

- `[ <length> | <percentage> ]` - Indicates that length or percentage can be values.
- `{1,4}` - Indicates that there must be at least one occurrence of the previous entity and atmost four occurrences. That is, the value should be minimum one length or percentage and maximum four length or percentages.
- `[ / [ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} ]?` - Similar to above but the question mark at the end indicates that this bit is ***optional***. That is, the `/` and length or percentage values following it are optional. If provided, they would be used as vertical border radii and if not, they'd be same as the horizontal radii.

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius:

> **`<length>`**
>
> *Denotes the size of the circle radius or the semi-major and semi-minor
>   axes of the ellipsis. It can be expressed in any unit allowed by the
>   **CSS `<length>` data types**. Negative values are invalid.*

And https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length described **CSS `<length>` data types**:

> The `<length>` CSS data type denotes distance measurements. **It is a
>   `<number>` immediately followed by a length unit (px, em, pc, in, mm,
>   …)**. Like for any CSS dimension, there is no space between the unit
>   literal and the number. The length unit is optional after the `<number>`
>   0.

So, in this case, you must use 4px (or 4em, 4in, ...) instead of 4.

Comment: it also says` [ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} [ / [ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} ]?`

Comment: @RobertRocha When you hover on <length> in MDN site, you will see a note, noticed that **`<length>`** is **`<length>`** of CSS data type.